# While deleting File System Task following error occurs "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: ssis

In `SSIS` while deleting the File System Task I got the following error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I was trying to do file move task. And in OLE DB source editor when I click on the build query tab I get the same error as above.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a question here. Could you edit this for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You should see a guid in your error. You can view code on your package and search for the guid.
Manually remove the associated xml and save